# how to place one image at the corner of another in relative layout in android?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I have two images. image A is a rectangle one and image B is a circular one. I want image B to be at the lower right corner of image A - 1/4th of it inside image A and the other 3/4th of it outside.

I am not sure how to do this using relative layout for my android app. Any help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this code may help you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imagepart"
  android:layout_width="72dp"
  android:layout_height="72dp"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  />


  <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgOnlinePart" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagepart" android:src="@drawable/online"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this might work for the left side...but what about the right side ? Specially if the rectangular image is on the left side of the screen and the circular image needs to be on the lower right side of the image ?

Comment: we can do with the relative layout only..need to set `alignParentRight` and `alignParentBottom` true. However, still not exactly what I wanted!